# Is it possible to run my python script which changes wallpaper on android?

Tags: python, android, android-wallpaper

I have created a script on Windows which changes my wallpaper every minute..I want to create such a script for my android. Is it possible to run such script on android and if it is then using which module can I change the mobile wallpaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3&hl=en

i dont know if that's what you are looking for but this app allows you to execute python on your android.

if you want to create an app, you can use Kivy, it's a module where you can make android apps and set background image like that:
[How to set a screen background image in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179155/how-to-set-a-screen-background-image-in-kivy)